# how to display cart items in cart pages with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, node-modules

this is the code which i used

```
getCartProducts:(userId)=>{
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
      let cartItems = await db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).aggregate([
        {
          $match:{user:objectId(userId)}
        },
        {
          $lookup:{
            from:collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION,
            let:{prodList:'$products'},
            pipeline:[
              {
                $match:{
                  $expr:{
                    $in:['$_id',"$$prodList"]
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            as:'cartItems'
          }
        }
      ]).toArray()
      
      resolve(cartItems)
    })
  }
```

router code:-

```
router.get('/cart',varifiedLogin,async(req,res)=>{
  
  let products = await userHelpers.getCartProducts(req.session.user._id)
  console.log(products);
  
  res.render('user/cart')
})
```

output i am getting:-

```
[
  {
    _id: 5fac03eed5f7b103a8906c03,
    user: 5fa8f0dbd417a11f6db37544,
    products: [
      5fac03eed5f7b103a8906c02,
      5fac06f454045e0403e470e0,
      5fac268d2071f006ff398666
    ],
    cartItems: []
  }
]
```

this is the expected output. i should be getting objects inside the cartItems.
_id is the product id
user field having the user id
the product having 3 items which i added to the cart.
and inside cart item i need to get the products as array.

```
[
  {
    _id: 5fac03eed5f7b103a8906c03,
    user: 5fa8f0dbd417a11f6db37544,
    products: [
      5fac03eed5f7b103a8906c02,
      5fac06f454045e0403e470e0,
      5fac268d2071f006ff398666
    ],
    cartItems: [[Object],[Object]]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an  array of second Argument in `$in`. `$in` takes exactly 2 arguments.

like this-

`$in: ['$_id', ["$$prodList"]]`